# Formatting credit card number in a number_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string-formatting

I have a Rails form that I use to take in credit card information from the users. I am trying to figure out how I can format the credit card number so that is is split into chunks of 4 while the user is typing it in and not one long string like the following:

```
4242424242424242 -> 4242 4242 4242 4242
```

The code in the form that I have for taking that value is as follows:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
   <div class="roboto bold black field-label">
     <%= t("app.label.credit_card_number") %>
   </div>
   <%= number_field_tag 'cc_number', '', class: 'field', placeholder: t("app.devise.registrations.placeholder.credit_card_number"), pattern: '\d*' %>
</div>
```

I have been digging and I can't find any option that can be passed as a "format". Any suggestion or guidance would be appreciated.

I have looked into using the number helpers (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html) and I don't see any option from that that is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: you can do like this `str= "4242424242424242" => "4242424242424242"` and  `str.chars.each_slice(4).map(&:join).join(" ")` => "4242 4242 4242 4242"`

Comment: @kgangadhar refer back to my question, please. I don't think this will actually split it into chunks of 4 as the user is typing it into the form field.